# Random permalink key in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I want to have a custom permalink for each new post in WordPress like:  http://mysite.com/x5Kvy6 (like bit.ly).

I tried this little script, but it adds only 5-digit numbers to the post title in the permalink.

```
function wp_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent ) {

if($slug!=""){
  $random=rand(11111,99999); //I needed 5 digit random
  $slug .= "-" . $random;
}
return $slug;

}
```

How can I make a random key instead of the post title?

I have not researched URL shorteners or redirection methods.

Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function wp_unique_post_slug($col,$table='wp_posts'){
     global $wpdb;

     $alphabet = array_merge( range(0, 9), range('a','z') );

     $already_exists = true;
     do {

         $guidchr = array();
         for ($i=0; $i<32; $i++)
         $guidchr[] = $alphabet[array_rand( $alphabet )];


         $guid = sprintf( "%s", implode("", array_slice($guidchr, 0, 12, true)) );

       // check that GUID is unique
       $already_exists = (boolean) $wpdb->get_var("
       SELECT COUNT($col) as the_amount FROM $table WHERE $col = '$guid'
       ");

      } while (true == $already_exists);

     return $guid;
}
```

This can be optimised in a number of ways.

Also regarding this `wp_unique_post_slug()` -- yikes watch out for the name spacing. Wordpress already uses this function name

Comment: This will do the job. But why are you going through 32 iterations in the for loop and only using 12 of them later on?

Comment: Great! It work well! I replace the fonction in post.php in wordpress core. But when i edit my post, the permalink change each time. Can you tell me how to avoid this? And i can't edit the permalink with a custom keyword, any idea? Thanks for all!

Comment: it may be worth asking another question to elaborate in greater detail. You shouldn't really be editing any wordpress core files.

Comment: Ok i followed your instruction:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763795/permalink-change-each-post-update-in-wordpress.

Comment: this code get "Cannot redeclare wp_unique_post_slug()" error message

Answer (score 1):

```
if($slug!=""){
   $random=rand(11111,99999); //I needed 5 digit random
   $slug = $random;
}
```

.= is for concat of strings.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use [Mwayi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762070/random-permalink-key-in-wordpress/11762698#11762698) is using the filter `wp_unique_post_slug`, as `function wp_unique_post_slug()` will conflit with WP own function. Inside WP function we find this filter hook.

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'unique_slug_so_11762070', 10, 6 );

function unique_slug_so_11762070( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) {
    $new_slug = so_11762070_unique_post_slug('guid');
    return $new_slug;
}

# From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762698
function so_11762070_unique_post_slug($col,$table='wp_posts'){
     global $wpdb;

     $alphabet = array_merge( range(0, 9), range('a','z') );

     $already_exists = true;
     do {

         $guidchr = array();
         for ($i=0; $i<32; $i++)
         $guidchr[] = $alphabet[array_rand( $alphabet )];


         $guid = sprintf( "%s", implode("", array_slice($guidchr, 0, 12, true)) );

       // check that GUID is unique
       $already_exists = (boolean) $wpdb->get_var("
       SELECT COUNT($col) as the_amount FROM $table WHERE $col = '$guid'
       ");

      } while (true == $already_exists);

     return $guid;
}
```

Comment: You can wrap $new_slug = so_11762070_unique_post_slug('guid'); in an if statement so it doesn't change on every update:

$real_status = get_post_status($post_ID);
if ( in_array( $real_status, array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ))) {
$new_slug = so_11762070_unique_post_slug('guid'); 
}

Answer (score 0):

For SEO, you better keep the slug as meaningful as possible, ie. do not change the permalink to a random sequence.
Using [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortnit/), you still can use http://example.com/raNd0m permalink for sharing purposes in social networks or images from your site.

This way you win both **SEO** and **shortlinks**

---

I used http://ijassar.info/underrated to write a post about this specific subject