# Permalink change each post update in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I want to have a custom permalink for each new post in WordPress like: http://mysite.com/x5Kvy6.

```
function wp_unique_post_slug($col,$table='wp_posts'){
     global $wpdb;

     $alphabet = array_merge( range(0, 9), range('a','z') );

     $already_exists = true;
     do {

         $guidchr = array();
         for ($i=0; $i<32; $i++)
         $guidchr[] = $alphabet[array_rand( $alphabet )];


         $guid = sprintf( "%s", implode("", array_slice($guidchr, 0, 12, true)) );

       // check that GUID is unique
       $already_exists = (boolean) $wpdb->get_var("
       SELECT COUNT($col) as the_amount FROM $table WHERE $col = '$guid'
       ");

      } while (true == $already_exists);

     return $guid;
}
```

This script works well when i replace the fontion in post.php (wordpress core) but unfortunately the permalink change at each post uptade. 
How to avoid this? And how to edit a custom optional keyword (http://mysite.com/keyword).

Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Read this

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

[image]

Or

```
function wp_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent ) {

if($slug!=""){
  $random=rand(11111,99999); //I needed 5 digit random
  $slug = $random;
}
return $slug;

}
```

Comment: Or this one is maybe better? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762070/random-permalink-key-in-wordpress/11762698#11762698

Comment: The problem is same, at every post uptdate, the permalink change (different key). A solution?

Answer (score 0):

You would like to try this plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: This plugin is only useful for assigning custom permalinks for individual posts, pages, tags or categories. For my project, i need this be done automaticly. Thanks.